Creating batch hyperlinks in either InDesign CC or exported PDF using Acrobat Pro
I have created a data merge document in InDesign with food products and information that will have hyperlinks created when someone clicks on them. My colleague is going through and individually creating links using Acrobat Pro but am wondering if there is a batch way to do this?


You can add hyperlinks in Indesign via the Hyperlinks Panel. https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/hyperlinks.html
